# git checkout branch without deleting the files deleted in it

Tags: git

Here is the situation I'm facing:

A directory full of generated files where commited to the repo by mistake. They obviously shouldn't have been, so I want to remove them:

```
$ git rm --cached foo/*
$ cat > foo/.gitignore
*
!.gitignore
$ git add foo/
$ git commit -m "Ignored stuff in foo"
```

This almost solves it, but leaves a different problem. When I want to `git fetch && git checkout` on the production server, all the generated files in the foo/ directory will be removed. Is there some magic I could do about it on either side? Please not that simply ignoring them is not an option as they can be changed.

Comment: Is it too late to push non-fast-forward?

Comment: yup :/ at least i wouldn't want to go that far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a:

```
git fetch
git reset origin/master
git update-index --skip-worktree foo/*
git checkout --
```

The checkout *should* ignore the folder `foo` because of the [`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) command.

Comment: why is the reset origin/master there? Btw the problem is that this wouldn't download the foo/.gitignore either.

Comment: @r1pp3rj4ck I reset to `origin/master` because that is what you have just fetched (downloaded), assuming you are working on the `master` branch. The `.gitignore` will be there after the `git checkout`.

Comment: git update-index --skip-worktree foo says it's unable to mark file foo. If I use foo/*, then it works.

Comment: @r1pp3rj4ck right, I forgot it applies only on files. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way to do this, but I did it with this little hack:

The commit part is what I wrote in the question, the checkout is the tricky one:

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout origin/master && \
git log HEAD^..HEAD --summary --diff-filter=D \
| grep delete | awk '{print $4}' | xargs git checkout HEAD^ -- \
&& git reset HEAD
```

This way I checkout the latest commit in master, checkout everything that was deleted in the latest commit and then reset to HEAD so the deleted & checked-out file would be unstaged.

It works, but I still would like to see some nicer way for this for the next time this happens.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction:

The accepted answer seems like it would work in some cases, but didn't seem like a perfect fit for what I was trying to do, so here's another approach:

### Backstory:

I'm trying to keep track of what files some software generates, and so I'm committing various things into a git repo that I don't ever intend to share, just to see what's there.

Some files are created that are labeled as temp.  I want to capture them in git, but mostly, I want to ignore them, and not track changes regularly (but be able to, if I want to), so, I wanted to create a branch `with-temp-files`, check the files in there, but then *not* get rid of the files when switching back to my `main` branch, where I'd then add a `.gitignore` to ignore them while I'm on main.

### The problem with the accepted answer (for me):

When doing the `git reset`, I was just going resetting to `main` -- there is no `origin` (or any other remote), so that didn't make sense.  And I'm wanting to keep a branch that has the files, I just don't want them on my main branch.

### My solution, for my situation:

1. Starting from a worktree that's got these new files in it, but is otherwise pristine
2. `git add temp` -- add the extra files
3. `git commit` -- get them into the repo
4. `git branch with-temp-files` -- now create a new branch on the commit that has the files added, but *don't switch to it*.
5. `git reset HEAD^` -- reset main to back before the new commit, leaving `with-temp-files` as its own branch.  The working tree is left alone (the files are still there, now again in an untracked state).

### A potentially more generalize-able answer:

1. Assuming you have a tree that has these added files, but no other changes since adding them (if this is not your situation, then more care is needed; beyond the scope of this answer)
2. Determine the commit that contains the unwanted files, let's pretend it's `abc123`
3. Determine the commit that's prior to the unwanted files having been added, let's pretend it's `def456` (though it could be indirectly referenced with something like `origin/main`).
4. [optional, if you want to keep track of the branch] use either `git branch with-files abc123` or `git tag with-files abc123` (changing `with-files` to any name you desire)
5. Run `git reset def456` to go back to a state before the files were added.  Without other arguments *(e.g. `--hard`, which would remove things -- not what we want here)*, the reset should leave the new files in the worktree.

Hopefully this adds some additional insights for anyone else trying to work through similar situations.