# Apply only changes to new or updated files from a git branch

Tags: git

We are managing a branch *stubs* that is a trimmed version (a couple hundred fewer files) of `master`. Is there a mechanism (or even *hack* ..) that would permit pulling updates from *master* but ignoring the files not in the trimmed branch *stubs* ?

The intent is something like

```
  git checkout stubs
  git pull origin master --update-or-add-only  # This does not exist
```

where the `--update-or-add-only` would be replaced by actual logic. Or more likely a series of git commands.

Note this question that has a similar name has a completely different purpose (to ignore some local files) [git checkout branch without deleting the files deleted in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652188/git-checkout-branch-without-deleting-the-files-deleted-in-it)

**Update**  It is appearing unlikely that `git` supports something like this *directly*.  I am looking into a mixed approach of *cherrypicking* individual files via a script that looks for *new* and *modified* entries only.

Note: we will also need to push changes from the *stubs* **back** to *master*.   Once again it will likely only be possible by looking at recent *git commits* and finding which files are *new* or *modified* and then using bash script to copy them directly from a local clone of *stubs* to a local clone of *master*.

Comment: A commit contains a snapshot of all the files in the repo. It sounds like you’re asking to merge “part” of a commit? Is that right?

Comment: yes that's the intent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a partial merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527195/how-to-do-a-partial-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's get *pull* out of the question, because pulling is a red herring: `git pull` means, roughly speaking, run `git fetch`, then run `git merge`.  The action you're concerned with here is merging.

> **Update** It is appearing unlikely that `git` supports something like this *directly*. I am looking into a mixed approach of *cherrypicking* individual files via a script that looks for *new* and *modified* entries only.

Let's go back to the basics: Git implements version control by making *full snapshots of every file*.  These are in commits.  Commits are numbered, with big ugly hash IDs.  Each commit has two parts: the snapshot, and some metadata.  The metadata shows who made the commit, when, and so on, and contains the number(s) of its parent commits.

Now look at your question again: you want *new* files and *modified* files.  A commit, standing by itself, *has no new files*.  It has no modified files.  It has no deleted files.  It just has *files:* it is simply a snapshot.  You find something to be "new" or "modified" by *comparing* the snapshot to some other snapshot.

Which snapshot shall we compare, to which other snapshot?  That's the key to solving your problem: you must pick the right set of snapshots and direct Git to do the right comparisons.  Do you want one single comparison?  Do you want many comparisons?  Which ones do you want done, when, and what do you want to do with each comparison's result?

Realizing this, and looking at how `git merge` itself operates, will tell you whether `git merge` can be helpful.  Knowing this, and looking at how `git cherry-pick` works, will tell you whether `git cherry-pick` can be helpful.  Or, perhaps you should simply write your own tool—a script that invokes various Git *plumbing commands*<sup>1</sup> that will do what you want done.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git divides its commands into *porcelain* or user-facing commands, vs *plumbing* commands.  These are typically tools to do some specific job, but porcelain commands typically offer both options *and* user configuration.  For instance, `git pull` runs two Git commands, but some users want the second command to be `git rebase` instead of `git merge`, so you can configure `git pull` to run `git rebase` instead of `git merge`.  That in turn means that if you are 100% sure you want, in some script, to run `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, you *should not* use `git pull` because it might run `git rebase` instead!

Git's attempt to divide these is not completely successful, but some commands, such as `git for-each-ref` and `git rev-list`, are definitely not end-user-oriented, while others like `git log` and `git diff` are, or try to be.  The `git diff` command has multiple plumbing commands that implement various parts: `git diff-index`, `git diff-tree`, `git diff-files`.  None of those read user configuration.  The `git diff` porcelain command *does* read user configuration.  So in a script, you would generally want to figure out which plumbing command to use, so as not to have your script break due to user configuration.

---

#### `git merge`

Merge is a big and complicated command, but if we ignore various options, such as `--squash`, and edge cases such as when `git merge` does a fast-forward instead of merging, it ends up being relatively simple for *most* cases:

- The merge operation takes two commits: the current commit, at the tip of the current branch, and some other commit, at the tip of some other branch.
- Merge uses the *commit graph* to identify a *merge base* commit.  This is the best common commit: of all the commits that are on *both* branches, one of them is "best".  (Technically this is the [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) of the DAG formed by the commits' parent/child relationships in the commit graph.)
- Merge now performs not one but *two* diffs.  The two diffs compare the common ancestor—the merge base—to *each of the two branch tip commits:*

  ```
            I--J   <-- current-branch (HEAD)
           /
  ...--G--H
           \
            K--L   <-- their-branch
  ```

  Here, the two branch tip commits are `J`, the last commit on our current branch, and `L`, the last commit on the other branch.  The best shared commit is obviously commit `H` as it is where the branches rejoin in history: all commits up through and including `H` are on both branches, and `H` is "closest to the end" (non-technically-speaking; for the technical definition of LCA, see the Wikipedia link).

  These two differences, which ignore all the intervening commits, produce a set of added, modified, deleted, and/or renamed files.<sup>2</sup>  When files are modified, they produce a list of changes that will transform the merge-base copy of some file into the branch-tip copy of the same file.<sup>3</sup>

Having obtained the correct differences and identified the correct files, merge's work is now to *combine* the various changes.  The combined changes are then applied to the snapshot from the *merge base*.  The result is a new snapshot, that takes "our changes", but also takes "their changes".  The terminology for this is a *three-way merge*.  See also [Why is a 3-way merge advantageous over a 2-way merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/1256452)

In some cases, the combining process goes awry because Git *can't* combine the two sets of changes.  In these cases, `git merge` *stops in the middle of the operation*.  The new snapshot is not yet made.  You now have the job of figuring out the *correct* snapshot, arranging for that correct snapshot to be in Git's *index*, and then finishing the merge.

The finished merge is special in exactly one way: instead of a single parent commit—the normal parent in our drawing above would be commit `J`—the merge commit that Git makes, or that you make after you resolve conflicts, has *two* parents, `J` and `L`.  This means that a future `git merge` operation that uses the commit graph will find a different merge base, because now commits `K-L` will be on our branch.  Commit `H`, the old merge base, won't be the merge base in a *later* merge.

Other than this alteration to the graph, a merge commit is otherwise exactly the same as any other commit: it has some metadata, saying who made it, when, and why (the log message), and it has a snapshot.  The snapshot is the one that was in Git's index when the merge completed, just as any `git commit` makes a snapshot of what is in Git's index.

**What you want to do is similar, but you definitely want to *discard* some changes.**  Sometimes, you want to keep some files the way they appear in your own branch tip commit.  Sometimes you don't.  If you let `git merge` complete the merge and make its own commit, that's the wrong result.  But `git merge` lets you *stop* the command, as if there had been a conflict, before making the new commit, using the `--no-commit` option.  This leaves everything else set up as usual, but now you can alter what's in Git's index, before you finish the merge.

Will that do what you want?  Maybe—*if* `git merge`'s commit graph manipulations are what you want *and* you can come up with the right set of manipulations *you* should make to alter Git's index to contain what *you* want it to contain.

---

<sup>2</sup>In Git, this is the job of the *merge strategy*.  There is a new merge strategy being worked on now, called `merge-ort`, which I have yet to catch up on.  For now, I'm talking about the `recursive` or `resolve` strategy, where I'm assuming a single merge base and therefore both strategies do the same thing.

<sup>3</sup>This gets into an interesting question: what does it mean for some file to be *the same file?*  [If you look very closely at this question, it becomes harder and harder to answer.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(philosophy))  Git's answer is usually that a file whose path name in the merge base is `path/to/file` must be the same file as a file in the branch-tip commit whose name is also `path/to/file`, but if you've *renamed* files, this gets murkier.

---

#### `git cherry-pick`

Cherry-picking is not as complicated as `git merge`: it makes a single ordinary (non-merge) commit that attempts to duplicate the changes from some other commit.  The surprise here is that `git cherry-pick` uses Git's merge machinery.

Remember again that each commit has the two parts: data—the snapshot—and metadata.  The *metadata* for a cherry-pick will be the same as for any ordinary commit.  But how should Git get the *data?*

What we want from `git cherry-pick` is to reproduce what happened in some existing commit.  But as we just observed yet again, commits *don't store changes*.  How can we tell what happened in some previous commit?  The answer is: we pick *two* previous commits and compare them.  Which two previous commits do we pick?  That's obvious after a moment of thought and a look at the commit graph:

```
...--o--o--P--C--o--o--...   <-- some-branch
  ...
    ...--o--T   <-- current-branch (HEAD)
```

Here we are with commit `T`, our target for the cherry-pick, all checked out in our work-tree, with us ready to work on it.  But the work we'd like to do now was already done, in commit `C`, the child of parent `P`.  What does that mean?  Well, it means that if we compare the *snapshot* in parent `P` to the *snapshot* in child `C`, we'll see the *changes* we'd like to make to our target snapshot `T`.

So, we need a diff from `P` to `C`.  Git can certainly do that: commit `C` contains in its metadata the (single) parent hash ID for commit `P`, so Git can run the diff and see what changed.  Then Git can try to apply these changes to the current snapshot, in our target commit.

What people have found over time is that this "apply some other change" works better when it is treated as a three-way merge.  We simply designate commit `P` as the "merge base" and `T`, our current commit, as our current commit, with commit `C`—the child of our chosen merge base `P`, and of course the argument to `git cherry-pick`, as the other commit.  Git then finds what *we* changed from `P` to `T`, and what *they* changed from `P` to `C`, and combines them.

If the combining goes well, `git cherry-pick` makes the commit on its own.  The commit it makes isn't a merge commit though:

```
...--o--o--P--C--o--o--...   <-- some-branch
  ...
    ...--o--T--C'   <-- current-branch (HEAD)
```

Here, the new commit is an ordinary single-parent commit, with parent `T`.  I've called the new commit `C'` because it is, sort of, a *copy* of commit `C`: the diff from `T` to `C'` is the same, sort of, as the diff from `P` to `C`.  (The line numbers of various changes might differ, and if you had to resolve merge conflicts, the diffs themselves will differ up in exactly those places where you did something to fix the conflict.)

You *can* get `git cherry-pick` to avoid doing the final commit, even if there are no conflicts.  Just add the `--no-commit` argument.  The cherry-pick will stop, just like merge will stop.  You now have a chance to change what's in Git's index, so that the final commit—from `git cherry-pick --continue` or `git commit`—has contents that *aren't* the result of the automated three-way merge.

**What this means for you is that you will have to do the same kind of work as you would do for `git merge --no-commit`.**  You will need to determine which changes to keep and which ones to discard.

#### Writing your own command

If neither of these methods seems to produce the results you want, consider doing your own `git diff` (using the appropriate plumbing commands, of course, so that you don't get tripped up by user configurations).  You can find the hash IDs of the appropriate commit(s) using `git rev-parse`, which is a very handy plumbing command.  (Sometimes you can use names, but generally, it's a good idea to turn the names into the appropriate raw hash IDs.  See [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for the various ways to spell a commit hash ID for `git rev-parse`.)

Note that `git diff --name-status` will show you the file names and a status letter for the result of each diff.  For instance, if you diff the parent and child commits that `git cherry-pick` would use:

```
git diff <hash-of-P> <hash-of-C>
```

you'll see some set of changes, and in those set of changes, you may also see an action of the form *delete some file entirely* or *create some new file*.  If you enable rename detection, you may see an action of the form *rename old name to new name*.  With `git diff --name-status`, you'll see `A` (add new file), `D` (delete file), `R` (rename file), or `M` (modify file) as the status.<sup>4</sup>  You can use this to decide whether a file is "new", for instance.

If you then decide you'd like to run a standard three-way merge algorithm on some *specific file content*, you will need to extract the three input files from three commits (or wherever they might come from).  The `git merge-file` command will then be able to perform that merge, possibly with conflicts.

Note that this amounts to writing your own *merge strategy*, and in general, writing merge strategies is *hard*.  See also footnote 2.

---

<sup>4</sup>The full possible set of letters for a standard diff is `ABCDMRT`; in a merge conflict situation, you can get status code `U`.  `B` is only possible if you use the `-B` option; `C` is only possible if you use the `-C` option; and `R` occurs only when rename detection is enabled, but this is a user configuration item.  `T` represents a type-change, e.g., from file to symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout stubs
git pull origin master --update-or-add-only  # This does not exist
```

No, it doesn't exist, but it's very easy to do:

```
git checkout stubs^0   # do the full merge as a throwaway
git merge master       # 
git checkout stubs     # now do a handroll merge and take what you want
git merge -s ours --no-commit master
git ls-files | xargs -r git checkout @{1} --
```